# Set the value of an input field with $_GET array in php

Tags: php, get

I want to set the value of the following input field using the $_GET array:

```
<input id="filterfeld" name='filterfeld' onkeyup="filterRows()" >
```

I have tried the following:

```
<input id="filterfeld" name='filterfeld' onkeyup="filterRows()" value="<?php echo $_GET['filterfeld']?>">
```

The URL looks like this:

http://localhost/benutzerdaten/index.php?filterfeld='A'

Can anyone tell me why the value of the input field doesnt change?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: value of the input field doesnt change means?

Comment: Your second example works fine. If you view the page source is the value correct? Also, a sidenote, you don't need to use quotes around the query param in the URL, it is automatically a string so unless you have some functional reason you probably don't need them

Comment: @BrettGregson The quotes caused the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inspecting the input field in the browser's console.

Try doing `var_dump( $_GET['filterfeld'] );` outside of input element and see whats the value.

Is your `$_GET['filterfeld']` an **A**rray? that could be the reason you are always getting filterfeld='A'?